# How to Retrieve Name of .lnk (short cut) file

Tags: c#, path, filenames, shortcut

Hey does anyone know how to get the name of a shortcut file(.lnk) from filepath?

For example if the shortcut is at the following location...

```
"C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\StartMenu\Internet Explorer.lnk"
```

I want just the Internet Explorer part as seen in properties of the file under name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(<filepath>);` should give you what you are looking for.

Comment: I think he's after where the the path the link is linking to, not the name of the link file itself.